# PHP Rest API for getting individual account transactions

Tags: yodlee

Using Yodlee rest api, I am able to get all transactions pertaining to one user. But I want to get transactions of a single account of the user. Is there any rest url to get the data?

Also please confirm if I can get the following data points from user transactions.
Merchant Category Code
Merchant Unique ID given by Bank/Visa

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

yes,
I am hoping that you are using the developer portal for doing these calls, else you can append the following to your URL which is in BOLD below

you can use the following URL for getting information of a single account under a user using the

https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/srest/restserver/v1.0/jsonsdk/**DataService/getItemSummaryForItem1**

you can get the details of the parameters  to be passed at the below API reference guide

https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/REST_API_Reference/getItemSummaryForItem1

Hope this helps.
--Vijay